# Android App getting crash and not Converting editText to String

Tags: android

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         edittext.setText("10.0.2.2");
    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            return false;
        }


    });
}
```

//getting crash at this line

```
   String SERVER_IP = edittext.getText().toString();
```

Comment: post the original code

Comment: Did you define `SERVER_IP` in field section? If yes, then you're getting `NullPointerException` because `edittext` is not initialized yet and trying to get their text in field section.

Answer (score 1):

Put "private EditText edittext;" declaration outside of onCreate method so that it can be accessed from other methods as well.

Comment: It already can be accessed from other methods, notice that where he initiates his edittext there is no declaration. Not to mention if this were the problem it would not compile, whereas the OP says that it crashes

Comment: Agreed. An oversight on my part

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is all one block of code, your edittext is probably `null`, because the code that you put in your activity that is not called in a method is called immediately. Try putting the `String SERVER_IP;` outside your method, and the line `SERVER_IP = edittext.getText().toString()` inside your `onKeyListener`. This should solve your problem